# What are the opposites of "put the finger in your mouth" & "stick your tongue out"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When I play with my toddler, I often see him **put his finger in his mouth** & **stick his tongue out**.

So, I say "**don't put your finger in your mouth**" & "**don't stick your tongue out of your mouth**".

I may want to say "**put your finger out of your mouth**" & "**stick your tongue in your mouth**".

But it seems people prefer to say "**keep your finger out of your mouth**" & "**keep your tongue in your mouth**". They seem to use **keep** rather than "**put**" & "**stick**".

What are the opposites of "**put the finger in your mouth**" & "**stick your tongue out**"?

Answer (score 1):

If you [keep out](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/keep-out) (i.e., stay out) your condition is opposite to your condition when [staying in](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stay-in).

However *keeping something in* is the opposite of *keeping something out*.

The difference is whether you are acting on yourself.

You could say

> **Put** your finger **out of** your mouth.

A better alternative would be

> **Take** your finger **out of** your mouth.

The word *take* may be seen as collaborative or neutral, with *put* hinting at more of an adversarial or passive role for the object of the verb.

For example, you may *put out* a dog or cat that needs to be outside the house.

On the other hand you might *take* a guest *out* to see a local attraction.

Alternatively, *take* could be thought of as having a leading, directing, pulling or inducing element to its meaning.

If *put* has a sense closer to mere placement then *take* could be a better choice for advising or commanding your little one to lead or draw his finger back out to a better place for himself.